# Combining Concatenate and wraps to get passthrough kwarg type hinting in python

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting

I've got a fun question I've been struggling with. Here's a toy bit of code:

```py
from functools import wraps

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Config(BaseModel):
    vegetable: str = "potato"
    fruit: str = "strawberry"


class SomeClass:
    @wraps(Config)
    def configure(self, something: str = "whoa", **kwargs):
        print(something)
        return Config(**kwargs)


s = SomeClass()
s.configure()
```

The goal here is for the type hinter to be able to tell the user that `self` doesn't have to be specified, `something` is a string, and expand the `kwargs`.

I was hoping to to combine `wraps` and Concatenate somehow to get the best of both worlds: annotating the default function args+kwargs (except kwargs) itself, and also annotating the available kwargs that come from the Config initialiser... but I've hit a wall with it.

Does anyone have a simple solution I'm overlooking?

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0692/

Comment: Yeah, that certainly goes a long way to addressing the issue, though it'll be years before the scientific python community catches up to 3.12 and I can use it.

Comment: No need for 3.12 - just import form `typing_extensions`.